# How can we find only the WebElements present on the viewport with using selenium python find_elements method?

Tags: selenium, web

I want to automate the task of scrolling through a web page and clicking on the buttons. But, when trying to find web elements with driver.find_elements() getting a list of all web elements which are not present on the viewport so clicking on them results in error "MoveTargetOutOfBounds"

```
    def like(self):
        likeButtonXpath = '//div[@aria-label="Like"]'
        try:
            a = ActionChains(self.browser)
            likeWebElements = self.browser.find_elements(
                By.XPATH, likeButtonXpath)
            for element in likeWebElements:
                try:
                    a.move_to_element(element).perform()
                    sleep(3)
                    element.click()
                except:
                    print("error while clicking button")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def scrollLike(self):
        last_height = self.browser.execute_script(
            "return document.body.scrollHeight")
        cnt = self.maxScroll
        curHeight = last_height
        while cnt >= 0:
            self.like()
            self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "")
            sleep(30)
            new_height = self.browser.execute_script(
                "return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height
            cnt -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to tell `driver.find_elements` to limit its search on the elements in the viewport. A possible workaround would be to compute the coordinates of the element and then scroll to them, but this is usually an hard task and almost impossible to get precise coordinates.

With javascript and `scrollIntoView` we can easily bring the desired element within the viewport.

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
```

By adding `block: "center"` the scroll will be executed in such a way that element is at the center of the viewport. By adding `behavior: "smooth"` the scroll will be smooth.

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', element)
```